# Replace content in oft template when sending through vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am trying to send mails automatically with an outlook template making minor changes to the text linked to the excel file. But the results do not appear when I choose an HTML format. Here is my code: I think the problem is with the .HTMLbody line because everything else in the code works fine. Could someone help?

```
Sub Test1()

'Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\600008809\Desktop\Reminder emails\Initial Survey.oft")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("G").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value) = "yes" _
           And LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "I").Value) <> "send" Then    
            'Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)    
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                 .To = cell.Value
                 .Subject = "abc!"
                 .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
                 .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "&lt;&lt; HiringManager &gt;&gt;", Worksheets("Tool").Range(4, 2))                                  
                'You can add files also like this
                '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
                Set .SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item("abc@xyz.com")
                .Send
                '.Display 'Or use Display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Cells(cell.Row, "I").Value = "send"
            Set OutMail = Nothing                
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is not good:

`.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "&lt;&lt; HiringManager &gt;&gt;", Worksheets("Tool").Range(4, 2)`

You have to replace the range value, or cell value in here so you should use

`.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "&lt;&lt; HiringManager &gt;&gt;", Worksheets("Tool").cells(4, 2).value`